# How to parameterize url slug with acts as taggable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I am using rails 4 and the [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) gem.  I am showing the tags in my view like this:

`<p id="tags">Tags: <%= raw @item.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t, tag_path(t.parameterize) }.join(', ') %></p>`

If I create a tag with a space "cool tag" it creates the url /tags/cool-tag which is how I want the url to look like for tags with spaces in the tag name.

However, this link leads to nowhere.  The actual link that gets created from my routes file looks like /tags/cool%20tag.

The corresponding line in my routes file looks like this:

`get 'tags/:tag',     to: 'items#tag', as: :tag`

and items_controller.rb:

```
class ItemsController < InheritedResources::Base

  def tag
    @tag = Tag.find_by_name(params[:tag])
    @tagged_items = Item.tagged_with(params[:tag])
  end
```

Is there a way to use parameterize on the other end in my routes so that /tags/cool-tag exists instead of /tags/cool%20tag?